# Mongoose: Match UserIDs with Embedded Document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

What i'm trying to achieve is matching people with each other.
To achieve this behavior, i'm embedding Match document to user's matches array.

Heres my `User` Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Match = new Schema({
    with: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    near: {type:String},
    createdAt: {type:Date, default: Date.now}
 });


const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, default: '' },
    surname: { type: String, default: '' },
    email: { type: String, default: '', },
    salt: { type: String, default: '' },
    hashed_password: { type: String, default: '' },
    interested: { type: [String] },
    about: { type: String },
    createdAt: {type:Date, default:Date.now},
    devices: {type: [String]},
    matches: [Match]
 });
```

But for a reliable application logic, 
The users must not be matched twice. My plan is inserting matched people inside their matches array together,

for example;

```
User A
_id: 123
matches: [{with: 456,near:California,createdAt:someDateTime}] 

User B
_id: 456
matches: [{with: 123,near:California,createdAt:someDateTime}]
```

Before a match occurs, i need to control whether any of the users matched before or not and it must be `atomic`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works:

```
const Match = new Schema({
    matchedIds: [ {type:string} ]
    near: {type:String},
    createdAt: {type:Date, default: Date.now}
 });
```

So `matchedIds` just contains the two userIDs. You can find the match then with:

```
db.match.find( { matchedIds: { $all: ["UserID 1", "UserID 2"] } } )
```

Comment: But it is not a model or schema itself, its just an embedded document. How can i query it then?

Comment: @AlicanYilmaz Sorry, I was too fast. Isn't it easier to store the match in its own collection? You can reference to it from both users and delete the references automatically if one user decides to undo the match.

Comment: My recent design was like that, i was collecting the matches in a seperate collection. But in that case, there is a big problem. When the query executed concurrently, the save() of the match collection runs twice simultaneously. This relies a big problem of incosistency. Here you can follow it; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718970/mongoose-atomic-save?rq=1